# Trying to write a SELECT statement but keep getting can't convert to int error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL coding and I'm struggling with a question that I have in my database class.

I DO NOT WANT THE ANSWER! I just need to be pushed into the right direction.
Below is the question that I'm struggling with.

Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each category that has products with these columns:
The CategoryName column from the Categories table
The count of the products in the Products table
The list price of the most expensive product in the Products table
Sort the result set so the category with the most products appears first.

Here is what I have so far:

```
     SELECT C.CategoryName, P.CategoryID, COUNT(*) Products, MAX(P.ListPrice)
     FROM Categories C, Products P
     WHERE C.CategoryName=P.CategoryID
     GROUP BY C.CategoryName,P.CategoryID ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc;
```

Everytime I run my SELECT query I keep getting this error:

```
     Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
     Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Basses' to data type int.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks!

--------------UPDATE-----------------------UPDATE----------------------

Hey everyone just wanted to know with the help of everyone I finally figured it out.

Here was the end result.

```
    SELECT C.CategoryName,COUNT(P.CategoryID) AS NumberOfProducts, MAX(P.ListPrice) AS
    MostExpensiveProduct
    FROM Categories C, Products P
    WHERE P.CategoryID=C.CategoryID
    GROUP BY C.CategoryName ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc;
```

Comment: Instead of a number - do you have the value `Basses` somewhere in your column `ListPrice`?

Comment: This:`WHERE C.CategoryName=P.CategoryID`looks a bit suspect and is most likely the source of the conversion error. Guessing it should be`WHERE C.ID=P.CategoryID`?

Comment: @jpw that would actually make sense since it the output is complaining about converting from VARCHAR to int

Comment: You should use ANSI-92 style joins instead of the much older style you are using here.

Comment: @juergend Yes the `Basses` is coming from the `CategoryName` column.

Comment: Also I think I found another error in my code. Because in the question it's looking for total number of products, I need to change the `COUNT (*) Products` to `COUNT (ProductsID)` because this will give me a count of every ProductID in the products table thusly giving me a count of all products.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely cause you're trying to compare `C.CategoryName` (which is most likely a VARCHAR type) to `P.CategoryID` which is likely an INT

Make sure you're using correct related fields when joining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are comparing varchar (categoryname) to int (categoryid) ,change the type of varchar to int  while using where condition or use column of same datatype while using where condition